# get a channel id discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating a bot using discord.js, I created a function in which when a specific command is used, a new channel is created in which an embed, with reaction, is sent.
I need to assign the id of the created channel to a var so that I can use it in other functions as well

I tried in a thousand ways to get the id of the channel that is created, I tried to do a lambda in a lambda, I can add the channel id to a var element but the function messageEmbed, that add the reaction to the embed, doesn't work, because it enters in the catch,

hope you can help me

this is my code:

```
const { Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'setup',
    description: "ruoli con emote",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, testChannelId) {

        console.log(testChannelId)
        const channel = '831573587579371580';
        const playem = '⏯️';
        const stopem = '⏹️';
        const nextem = '⏭️';
        const shuffleem = '';
        const loopem = '';
        const volume15 = '';
        const volume30 = '';
        const mute = '';


        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Nessuna canzone in riproduzione al momento :(')
            .setImage('https://images4.alphacoders.com/943/943845.jpg')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Rule 1', value: 'figo' },
                { name: 'Rule 2', value: 'hhj' },
                { name: 'Rule 3', value: 'tipo' }
            )
            .setFooter('il prefisso per questo server è: *');

        console.log('message: ' + message)
        console.log('args: ' + args)
        console.log('Discord: ' + Discord)
        console.log('client: ' + client)

        var botname = ' ' // setup messaggio con reazioni
        var idcanale 
        const createdChannel = await message.guild.channels.create(botname, { //Create a channel

            type: 'text', //Make sure the channel is a text channel
            permissionOverwrites: [{ //Set permission overwrites
                id: message.guild.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }],

        }).then(createdChannel => {
            idcanale = createdChannel.id;
            createdChannel.send(createdChannel.id, embed)}).then(function (messageEmbed) {
                  
            messageEmbed.react(playem);
            messageEmbed.react(stopem);
            messageEmbed.react(nextem);
            messageEmbed.react(shuffleem); 
            messageEmbed.react(loopem);
            messageEmbed.react(volume15);
            messageEmbed.react(volume30);
            messageEmbed.react(mute);

            client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
                if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
                if (user.bot) return;
                if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

                switch (reaction.emoji.name) {

                    case playem:
                        console.log('Pausa / resume');
                        client.commands.get('prova').execute(client, message, args, Discord, createdChannel.id);
                        break;

                    case stopem:
                        console.log('stop');
                        client.commands.get('stop').execute(client, message, args);
                        break;

                    case nextem:
                        console.log('Skip');
                        client.commands.get('skip').execute(client, message, args);
                        break;

                    case loopem:
                        console.log('loop');
                        client.commands.get('loop').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;

                    case shuffleem:
                            console.log('shuffle');
                            client.commands.get('shuffle').execute(client, message, args)
                            break;

                    case volume15:
                        console.log('volume15');
                        client.commands.get('volume15').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;

                    case volume30:
                        console.log('volume30');
                        client.commands.get('volume30').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;

                    case mute:
                        console.log('muto');
                        client.commands.get('mute').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;
                }
                reaction.users.remove(user)
            });

        }).catch(function () {
            console.log('Errore');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a parameter like e.g. `err` to your `function` in `catch` and display the error you're getting?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'react' of undefined

Comment: Your function isn't working because `messageEmbed` seems to be empty / undefined..

Comment: Is `messageEmbed` the embed you created at the top or do you want to create a new embed called `messageEmbed`?

Comment: messageEmbed is the function that add the reaction to the embed, if I remove the line: idcanale = createdchannel.id, the function work

Comment: Are you planning to use this `variable`? Because you are assigning it but it's never used after

Comment: yes I want to use this in other commands

Comment: What is `testChannelId` meant to be used for? And what about `channel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't actually your `channelID` issue that was the problem. It was actually getting an error when trying to react to the embed.

---

### Things I Modified:

I nested the two `then` methods, so one is inside of another. There may be other people telling me that it isn't a standard convention, but I welcome constructive criticism.

I also changed your `messageEmbed` to `reactEmbed` instead to avoid naming convention errors. I am confused by the way you said that `messageEmbed` is a function that adds the reaction to the embed, but I think I get what you were saying.

---

### Process:

1. Assigned unicode emojis to variables (already done)
2. Created embed aptly titled `embed`
3. `Console.log`-ed all the information (extraneous stuff, but you had that in your code. Since there's no harm in it, I left it there)
4. Created `botname` and `idcanale`; I think you mentioned that you wanted to pass the id of the channel for another function, so I left it there.
5. Created channel also aptly titled `createdChannel`
6. `then` got the id of the `createdChannel` and set it as `idcanale` as well as sent the embed
7. `then` (this is nested inside the other `then` method) reacted to the embed and called the embed `reactEmbed` to distinguish the names.
8. I left the rest of the code as is.

---

### Note:

I have no idea what `testChannelId` was (in the parameters) and since it didn't get called really at all except for the beginning, I simply just commented it out in the code below.

I also have no idea what `channel` stood for either, so I also commented it out. Basically, I tried to help you from the limited information in the prompt.

---

### Code:

```js
const { Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'setup',
    description: "ruoli con emote",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, testChannelId) {

        //console.log(testChannelId) what is this for?
        //const channel = '831573587579371580';
        const playem = '⏯️';
        const stopem = '⏹️';
        const nextem = '⏭️';
        const shuffleem = '';
        const loopem = '';
        const volume15 = '';
        const volume30 = '';
        const mute = '';


        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Nessuna canzone in riproduzione al momento :(')
            .setImage('https://images4.alphacoders.com/943/943845.jpg')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Rule 1', value: 'figo' },
                { name: 'Rule 2', value: 'hhj' },
                { name: 'Rule 3', value: 'tipo' }
            )
            .setFooter('il prefisso per questo server è: *');

        console.log('message: ' + message)
        console.log('args: ' + args)
        console.log('Discord: ' + Discord)
        console.log('client: ' + client)

        var botname = ' ' // setup messaggio con reazioni
        var idcanale = "" //first sets it to nothing
        const createdChannel = await message.guild.channels.create(botname, { //Create a channel
            type: 'text', //Make sure the channel is a text channel
            permissionOverwrites: [{ //Set permission overwrites
                id: message.guild.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }],
        }).then(createdChannel => {
            idcanale = createdChannel.id;
            createdChannel.send(idcanale)
            createdChannel.send(embed)
                .then(reactEmbed => {
                    reactEmbed.react(playem);
                    reactEmbed.react(stopem);
                    reactEmbed.react(nextem);
                    reactEmbed.react(shuffleem);
                    reactEmbed.react(loopem);
                    reactEmbed.react(volume15);
                    reactEmbed.react(volume30);
                    reactEmbed.react(mute);

                    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
                        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
                        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
                        if (user.bot) return;
                        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

                        switch (reaction.emoji.name) {

                            case playem:
                                console.log('Pausa / resume');
                                client.commands.get('prova').execute(client, message, args, Discord, idcanale); //replaced createdChannel.id w/ idcanale
                                break;

                            case stopem:
                                console.log('stop');
                                client.commands.get('stop').execute(client, message, args);
                                break;

                            case nextem:
                                console.log('Skip');
                                client.commands.get('skip').execute(client, message, args);
                                break;

                            case loopem:
                                console.log('loop');
                                client.commands.get('loop').execute(client, message, args)
                                break;

                            case shuffleem:
                                console.log('shuffle');
                                client.commands.get('shuffle').execute(client, message, args)
                                break;

                            case volume15:
                                console.log('volume15');
                                client.commands.get('volume15').execute(client, message, args)
                                break;

                            case volume30:
                                console.log('volume30');
                                client.commands.get('volume30').execute(client, message, args)
                                break;

                            case mute:
                                console.log('muto');
                                client.commands.get('mute').execute(client, message, args)
                                break;
                        }
                        reaction.users.remove(user)
                    });

                })
        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```